# Why doesen't it work to write this NSMutableArray to a plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist

edited.

Hey, I am trying to write an NSMutableArray to a plist.
The compiler does not show any errors, but it does not write to the plist anyway.
I have tried this on a real device too, not just the Simulator.

Basically, what this code does, is that when you click the `accessoryView` of a `UITableViewCell`, it gets the `indexPath` pressed, edits an `NSMutableArray` and tries to write that `NSMutableArray` to a plist. It then reloads the arrays mentioned (from multiple plists) and reloads the data in a `UITableView` from the arrays.

Code:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event touchesForView:sender] anyObject] locationInView:table]];

[arrayFav removeObjectAtIndex:[arrayFav indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[arraySub objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]]]];

NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arrayFav.plist"];
NSLog(@"%@ - %@", rootPath, plistPath); 


[arrayFav writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];    

// Reloads data into the arrays
[self loadDataFromPlists];

// Reloads data in tableView from arrays
[tableFarts reloadData];
```

CFShow() on the array *after* removing one of them shows this:

```
<CFArray 0x6262110 [0x2c810a0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 4, values = (
    0 : <CFNumber 0x6502e10 [0x2c810a0]>{value = +3, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    1 : <CFNumber 0x6239de0 [0x2c810a0]>{value = +8, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    2 : <CFNumber 0x6239dc0 [0x2c810a0]>{value = +10, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    3 : <CFNumber 0x6261420 [0x2c810a0]>{value = +40, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
```

DEBUG-INFO: `writeToPlist` shows YES, I have tried to release all the arrays before filling them up again, setting them to `nil`, set `atomically` to NO.

Comment: Why are you creating an NSNumber using `numberWithInt:` and then calling `intValue` on it? Why not just use the int... ?

Comment: Because `indexOfObject:` needs an object.

Comment: Please show the code where you are creating and adding the objects to `arrayFav` to begin with?  Most likely, the objects contain some type that is not compatible with plists.

Comment: NSString *plistFavPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrayFav" ofType:@"plist"];
 arrayFav = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFavPath];

Comment: The plist is an array with numbers in it.

Comment: A YES returned indicates it successfully wrote the file. Why do you think it didn't? Did you run it on the simulator and look at the plist file in the app's folder?  The problem may be in your reading of the file rather than in the writing.

Comment: Hah, you're right!
I checked the file now, and it actually gets written to..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments below, the actual problem here is that the plist is being read from and written to two different locations.  Somewhere in the app, there is code that reads the file into the array similar to this:

```
NSString *plistFavPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrayFav" 
                                                         ofType:@"plist"]; 
arrayFav = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFavPath];
```

This logic reads the array from the application's bundle, which is a read-only location and part of the distributed app.  Later when the edited array is persisted, code similar to this is used:

```
NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask,
                                                          YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [rootPath 
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arrayFav.plist"];
NSLog(@"%@ - %@", rootPath, plistPath); 
[arrayFav writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

The result here is that the updated file gets written to the app's documents directory, but it is never read from there, giving the appearance that the file is not being saved correctly. To correct this, you should change the code that reads the file to use the same path that you are writing to.

If you need to distribute a default version of the plist for use on the initial launch before the array has been edited, you could continue to include a version of the file in your bundle and then add code to your app delegate that check if the file exists in the documents directory and if it is not present, copies the bundle's default version of the file to the proper place.

Comment: What..? No? I am getting the path with this method: `NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"arrayFav.plist"];`

Comment: In that case then, it seems to me that what you may be doing is reading the plist from one place (your applications bundle) and writing it to another (your applications Document directory). Thus you would have two copies of the plist.  

When I asked in my comment to the original question above how you were creating the array to begin with, the code you gave indicated that you are reading the file from the bundle, so I assumed you were trying to write the updated file to the same place.  

After writing the file to the Documents directory, when you reload it, how are you getting the path?

Comment: In other words, where are you doing this:

   NSString *plistFavPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrayFav" ofType:@"plist"]; 
   arrayFav = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFavPath];

Is that only the first time the file is read, or does it happen on every launch, resulting in the changes you saved to the docs directory being ignored?

Comment: Jason, you are right, I am reading and writing to two different places. If you edit your answer, I'll choose it as the correct one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be able to fix it now ! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[yourMutableArray writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

This should work. NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray which has a [method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#jumpTo_66) to write to a plist.

Comment: Thanks, that should probably do it, but it does not seem to work. See updated post.

Comment: That should work.  Check your array contents to make sure that you have only NSString, NSData, NSArray or NSDictionary objects in it.  Check the BOOL result returned by writeToFile.  Read the description of writeToFile for more details.

Comment: The array actually contains `NSNumber`-s. Would that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

`writeToFile:atomically:` won't work if your array contains custom objects.

If your array contains custom objects that are not Plist objects (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSNumber, etc), then you will not be able to use this method. This method only works on Plist objects.

Another option would be to use the NSCoding protocol, and write your objects to disk that way.

Comment: The array contains `NSNumber`-s.

Comment: Edit: according to CFShow it actually contains CFNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Look at the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5).

phoneNumbers is a NSMutableArray

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender {
    NSString *error;
    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
            [NSArray arrayWithObjects: personName, phoneNumbers, nil]
            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Phones", nil]];
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict
                            format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
                            errorDescription:&error];
    if(plistData) {
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(error);
        [error release];
    }
    return NSTerminateNow;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but how do I make a NSDictionay out of ONE NSMutableArray?